# HTML string gets extra newline character if sent from server to client

Tags: javascript, java, spring, modelandview

I'm having trouble with string manipulation. I have some code written in java, that will use an xls translator to generate some html for me - in string form.

I use spring framework to communicate this string back to my web code, but when the string arrives in the javascript, it fails with an "invalid or unexpected token error. Furthermore, when the string is written to the console, it seems that the string now containts newline characters for each new tag.

For my javascript I really need the html to be all one line. 
here are some code bits:

```
    try {
        SimpleResultSet rs = dbClient.executeQuery("select MediaContent from call where id = " + callID);
        if (rs.next()) {
            media = rs.getString("MediaContent");
            mimeType = rs.getString("MediaTypeID");

            if(media.startsWith("<?xml")) {
                trace.info("XSLT: " + xltString);
                trace.info("Database XML: " + media);
                media = Transform(media, xltString, response);
                //trace.info("result HTML: " + media);

                if (!media.isEmpty()) {
                    media = media.replaceAll("\n\r", "")
                        .replaceAll("\n", "")
                        .replaceAll(System.lineSeparator(), "");
                }
            }

            //media = media.replaceAll("\"","\\\\\"");

        }
    } catch (DBException e) {
        trace.warning("Failed to get call content media for call id = " + callID, e);   
        return media;
    }
    trace.info("cleaned HTML: " + media);
    return media == null ? "" : media; 
}
```

At this point the trace printing out the cleaned HTML, shows the string all on one line, without any newline characters. The string is then propagated to the ModelAndView like this:

```
return new ModelAndView("media", "media", mediaStr);
```

and on the javascript side:

```
<script>
    var contentString =  "${media}";
    document.getElementById("mediaContentIFrame").srcdoc = contentString;
```

it is the contentString variable on the javascript side that fails with the invalid or unexpected token error.
The contentString is used to initialise the srcdoc property of an IFrame.

Comment: can you show how are calling data from backend? ur Javascript code.

Comment: You have already added two checks \r\n and \n.. Also add \r

Comment: I've updated the original post with how the contentString is used in javascript to initialise an IFrame. Will try out the \r option and give feedback in a minute.

Comment: The \r option seems to work - when the string arrive in javascript it does not contain the newline characters anymore, however of course javascript now wants the " characters to be escaped it seems.

Comment: @DirtyDeveloper - removing \r characters solved the problem. If you want to put that in answers, I can mark it as such.

Comment: @Harriet added as an answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have already added two checks \r\n and \n.. Also add \r and i hope it will start working :)